# Rust private struct fields and defaults and destructuring?

Tags: rust, default, destructuring

Let's say I create a struct.

```rust
mod foostruct {
    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct Foo {
        a: u64,
        pub b: u64,
    }
}
```

Is it true that this struct, because of the visibility rules can not be created externally with a default,

```
Foo { b: 42, ..Default::default() }
```

And, also cannot have it's visible members destructed?

```rust
let Foo { b, ... } = foo;
```

I was just having a conversation with a friend and both of these were brought up, and I just never thought of this. I was previously **always** using builders, and hadn't considered destruction/defaults as a detriment to the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these bits of code are sugar for something else, so we can reason about their characteristics by examining what they desugar to.

> ```
> Foo { b: 42, ..Default::default() }
> ```

Desugars to roughly:

```
{
    let temp: Foo = Default::default();
    Foo { b: 42, a: temp.a }
}
```

This is disallowed, because `Foo::a` is not visible.

> ```
> let Foo { b, .. } = foo;
> ```

Desugars to this (with an additional static type-check that `foo` is indeed a `Foo`):

```
let b = foo.b;
```

This *is* allowed because the private fields are never actually read.

Comment: [There is an open issue to (maybe) allow it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63538).